# Adding gif to Android Expanded Push Notification in Android N

Tags: android, android-notifications

I currently use BigPictureStyle in order to add pictures to expanded notifications in Android.

Is it possible to add a gif to an expanded notification preview?

Thank you

Comment: you asking like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoWUIJMOjdI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @appukrb How did you do it? I am looking to do something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I don't think we can use GIF in push notifications using native functionality. I have been through video that @appukrb posted and along with that I have found out that only QGraph (search for it on play store) provides push notifications with GIF. Otherwise I don't think it is achievable using 'remoteview'.